# Selecting a customer's first contract for calculating their age at that time in a COUNT?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to generate a customer summary of multiple years (e.g. 2000 to 2019).

For this, I want to list the amount of customers in each age bracket, and I'm trying to calculate how old each customer was when we received their first contract from them.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the {DATE_I_NEED}

I tried MIN(contract.contract_received) but it doesn't let me "nest aggregate functions".

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT customer.id) "customers",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN customer.form_of_address = 'Mr.' THEN customer.id END) "male",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN customer.form_of_address = 'Mr.'
        AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM AGE({DATE_I_NEED}, customer.day_of_birth)) BETWEEN 1 AND 24
        THEN customer.id END) "male_1_24"
FROM contract
INNER JOIN customer ON contract.customer = customer.id
WHERE contract.partner = '123'
AND contract.archived = false
```

Sample data:

```
contract.received | customer.id | customer.form_of_address | customer.day_of_birth
  '2018-06-13'          12345               'Mr.'                 '1998-07-27'
  '2014-06-13'          12345               'Mr.'                 '1998-07-27'
```

^It should take 2014 from here to calculate the age

Expected output:

```
customers | male | male_1_24
   300       161       27
```

Comment: Please add some minimized sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can just fetch the minimum contract_received first, then can join the  customer table to it. Also presumable you already have an age function having 2 parameters to calculate age -

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT customer.id) "customers",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN customer.form_of_address = 'Mr.' THEN customer.id END) "male",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN customer.form_of_address = 'Mr.'
        AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM AGE(contract_received, customer.day_of_birth)) BETWEEN 1 AND 24
        THEN customer.id END) "male_1_24"
FROM (SELECT customer, partner, archived, MIN(contract_received) contract_received
      FROM contract
      GROUP BY customer, partner, archived) c
INNER JOIN customer ON c.customer = customer.id
WHERE c.partner = '123'
AND c.archived = 'false'
```